# Slow Uninstall of SQL Server 2008 / 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, uninstall

Each of the components of SQL Server 2008 and 2005 take an age to uninstall - it's not that the bulk of the uninstall takes it's time, it's that it seems to get the the end of uninstalling each component and then take forever 'Configuring Components' - at which time the .log for the uninstall grows to 100MB+, and is littered with countless many of the below.  Anyone had any luck in quashing this problem?

```
...
1: sxsdelca 2: traceop 3: 749 4: 0 
1: scavenge 2: {ACE28263-76A4-4BF5-B6F4-8BD719595969} 3: {F03DBDB7-685B-2EAB-C01F-C8B3B9A1E18E} 4: {FFFA78A7-BD51-4255-8470-C4D4A85B49F5} 5: -1 6: 1607 
1: sxsdelca 2: traceop 3: 749 4: 0 
1: scavenge 2: {0C19D563-5F25-4621-BF10-01F741BD283F} 3: {F03DBDB7-685B-2EAB-C01F-C8B3B9A1E18E} 4: {FFFA78A7-BD51-4255-8470-C4D4A85B49F5} 5: -1 6: 1607 
1: sxsdelca 2: traceop 3: 749 4: 0 
1: scavenge 2: {7C8B5E63-821A-4DFB-BDFA-19854D88EC5C} 3: {F03DBDB7-685B-2EAB-C01F-C8B3B9A1E18E} 4: {FFFA78A7-BD51-4255-8470-C4D4A85B49F5} 5: -1 6: 1607 
1: sxsdelca 2: traceop 3: 749 4: 0 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The slowness of un-installing may be due to the fact, that the MSI-un-installer cannot delete files under %windir%winsxs`. However, do **NOT** manually delete things from %windir%\WinSxS. One solution might be un-installing *all* .NET Frameworks and *all* SQL related apps, possibly cleaning up with the windows installer cleanup utility. Then re-installing .NET Frameworks and finally re-installing SQL Server.

Comment: That's a big undertaking for a not guaranteed gain, though Luke - I did finally managed to get everything uninstalled / reinstalled, but the reinstall was suffering from the same problem.